# Crashing app in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash

I'm a high school student creating a simple app for a school project. This is my first time creating an app, using the Swift language, and using Xcode. 
Every time I run the app, it crashes before it opens. This is what is shown after it crashes:

[image: Error Message]

This is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var coffeeOutput: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var check1: UILabel!
    let things = UserDefaults.standard

    var coffeeShops = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    // 0 days: Int = 0
    // 1 highland: Int = 0
    // 2 starbucks: Int = 0
    // 3 heine: Int = 0
    // 4 quills: Int = 0
    // 5 bean: Int = 0
    // 6 sunergos: Int = 0
    // 7 press: Int = 0
    // 8 please: Int = 0



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func highlands(sender: UIButton) {
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "highland")+1, forKey: "highland" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "days")+1, forKey: "days" )
        things.synchronize()
   }

    @IBAction func downtown(_:AnyObject) {

        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "please")+1, forKey: "please" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "starbucks")+1, forKey: "starbucks" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "press")+1, forKey: "press" )
        things.synchronize()
    }

    @IBAction func germantown(_:AnyObject) {
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "heine")+1, forKey: "heine" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "bean")+1, forKey: "bean" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "sunergos")+1, forKey: "sunergos" )
        things.synchronize()
    }

    @IBAction func school(_:AnyObject) {
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "quills")+1, forKey: "quills" )
        things.synchronize()
    }

    @IBAction func homework(_:AnyObject) {

        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "days")+1, forKey: "days" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "starbucks")+1, forKey: "starbucks" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "heine")+1, forKey: "heine" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "quills")+1, forKey: "quills" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "sunergos")+1, forKey: "sunergos" )
        things.synchronize()
    }

    @IBAction func meeting(_:AnyObject) {

        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "days")+1, forKey: "days" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "starbucks")+1, forKey: "starbucks" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "heine")+1, forKey: "heine" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "quills")+1, forKey: "quills" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "bean")+1, forKey: "bean" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "press")+1, forKey: "press" )
        things.synchronize()
    }

    @IBAction func toGo(_:AnyObject) {

        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "starbucks")+1, forKey: "starbucks" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "heine")+1, forKey: "heine" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "bean")+1, forKey: "bean" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "sunergos")+1, forKey: "sunergos" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "please")+1, forKey: "please" )
        things.synchronize()
    }

    @IBAction func hang(_:AnyObject) {

        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "highland")+1, forKey: "highland" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "days")+1, forKey: "days" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "heine")+1, forKey: "heine" )
        things.synchronize()

    }

    @IBAction func morning(_:AnyObject) {

        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "days")+1, forKey: "days" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "starbucks")+1, forKey: "starbucks" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "heine")+1, forKey: "heine" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "bean")+1, forKey: "bean" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "sunergos")+1, forKey: "sunergos" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "press")+1, forKey: "press" )
        things.synchronize()
    }

    @IBAction func midday(_:AnyObject) {
        //0 2 3 4 6 7 8
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "days")+1, forKey: "days" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "starbucks")+1, forKey: "starbucks" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "heine")+1, forKey: "heine" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "quills")+1, forKey: "quills" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "sunergos")+1, forKey: "sunergos" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "press")+1, forKey: "press" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "please")+1, forKey: "please" )
        things.synchronize()
    }

    @IBAction func night(_:AnyObject) {
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "days")+1, forKey: "days" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "highland")+1, forKey: "highland" )
        things.set(things.integer(forKey: "heine")+1, forKey: "heine" )
        things.synchronize()
    }

    // 0 days: Int = 0
    // 1 highland: Int = 0
    // 2 starbucks: Int = 0
    // 3 heine: Int = 0
    // 4 quills: Int = 0
    // 5 bean: Int = 0
    // 6 sunergos: Int = 0
    // 7 press: Int = 0
    // 8 please: Int = 0

    @IBAction func computeShop(_:AnyObject) {
        var max = things.integer(forKey: "days")
        var maxKey = "days"
        for element in UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys.elements{
            if(things.integer(forKey: element)>max){
                max = things.integer(forKey: element)
                maxKey = element
            }
        }
        self.coffeeOutput.text = maxKey

        for element in UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys.elements{
            things.set(0,forKey: element)
            things.synchronize()
        }


    }
}
```

Here is the stacktrace:
{

2017-04-13 12:13:04.411 button[95215:59212987] -[**NSCFNumber _getCString:maxLength:encoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003
2017-04-13 12:13:04.574 button[95215:59212987] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber _getCString:maxLength:encoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b4f4d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010af5621e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b564f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b47a005 ___forwarding_** + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b479b88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b42e89b CFStringGetCString + 171
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b43e77d CFLocaleCreateCanonicalLocaleIdentifierFromString + 77
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b43e327 _CFLocaleCopyCurrentGuts + 487
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b43e109 +[NSLocale currentLocale] + 9
    9   Foundation                          0x000000010aa19376 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) init] + 1637
    10  Foundation                          0x000000010aa18cb5 +[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) standardUserDefaults] + 81
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010b9438df ___UIApplicationMainPreparations_block_invoke_2 + 53
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010eb7d978 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010eba70cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010eb8865f _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1450
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010eb88059 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010ef56736 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010ef56211 start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) 
}

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Unrelated to your crash but get rid of all of those needless calls to `synchronize`.

Comment: I'd bet your crash has to do with an IBOutlet/IBAction not lining up with the storyboard. You probably have one initiated in the storyboard that goes nowhere.

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: have you tried to create a new project, and copy past you code without touching the storyboard ? this could help corner your issue

Comment: What's the stack trace look like, in the Debug navigator?  Can you tell what's calling this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the file owner of your xib file
2. Check the connections to your view controller (Outlet and Actions)

after fixing those, clean the build (cmd+shift+k) and rerun it.

if it still crashes,
put break points in all your classes and find out where exactly it crashes. Please give us some extra info, we would try to help more

note: synchronize is not necessary

Comment: I'm a beginner so you'll have to spell things out for me, sorry. Do I have .xib files for each of my buttons in my app? If so, all of their custom classes are UIButton and I can't change them.

Comment: Here is the stacktrace:

Comment: iOS screens can be developed by following ways:
1. Programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Give a breakpoint in Your ViewDidLoad method. If it crashes even before coming there. Then just check your connection in the storyBoard. You might have deleted some connections and storyboard may be still trying to find that.

Comment: This should a comment since it doesn't really solve the problem, it just offers suggestions to help debug the issue.